# Keep TikZ arrows on foreground with animategraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, tikz-arrows

I am using beamer and I'd like to put an arrow with TikZ on a movie created with \animategraphics.

No problem when I am using only one frame, for example:

```
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\centerline{Title}}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (salimg) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim = 15mm 10mm 10mm 10mm,clip,width=\textwidth]{FirstImage.png} };                          
    \node[inner sep=2pt,fill=magenta] (sectcall) at (6,-3) {\tiny Hi!};
    \draw[<-,thick] ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=1.5cm]salimg.south east) -- (sectcall.west);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

But when I insert the animation, part of the arrow is not visible because it goes underneath the frames

```
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\centerline{Title}}
   \begin{tikzpicture}        
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (salimg) at (0,0) {\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,trim = 15mm 10mm 10mm 10mm,clip,width=\textwidth]{6}{Image0}{001}{010} }                          
    \node[inner sep=2pt,fill=magenta] (sectcall) at (6,-3) {\tiny Hi!};
    \draw[<-,thick] ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=1.5cm]salimg.south east) -- (sectcall.west);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I tried with declaring pgf layers but nothing will do. Any idea or advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Animated graphics produced with the animate package are rendered within PDF annotations (interactive regions) which live, by design of AdobeReader, in a separate layer *in front* of the page content.

Thus, you cannot draw arrows or something else on top of animations, unless you make it part of the animation:

```
%\zeropad{<width template>}{<number to be formatted>}
\makeatletter
\let\zeropad\@anim@pad
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{\centerline{Title}}
 \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{6}
   \multiframe{10}{i=1+1}{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \node[inner sep=0pt] (salimg) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim = 15mm 10mm 10mm 10mm,clip,width=\textwidth]{Image\zeropad{0000}{\i}}};
       \node[inner sep=2pt,fill=magenta] (sectcall) at (6,-3) {\tiny Hi!};
       \draw[<-,thick] ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=1.5cm]salimg.south east) -- (sectcall.west);
     \end{tikzpicture}
   }
 \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Fantastic solution and explanation! Thanks AlexG!